# tensorflowライブラリにおけるplaceholderのちょっとした疑問

Tags: python, tensorflow

tensorflowでplaceholderを使用するとき、feed_dictでfeedする際にその変数が適用されるタイミングというのは、placeholderが宣言されている時点でfeedされるのでしょうか？
それとも、placeholderで宣言された変数が式として使われる時でしょうか？
言葉で説明するのが難しいので下に例を書かせていただきます。

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[2, 2], name='tf_x')    ←①
y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[2, 2], name='tf_y')

#// 別のコードを挟む //

add = tf.add(x, y, name='add_op')     ←②

g = tf.Graph()
with tf.Session(graph=g) as sess:
    feed = {'tf_x:0' : 4,
            'tf_y:0' : 5}
    result = sess.run('add_op:0', feed_dict=feed)
```

この場合、①と②のどちらの時点で変数がfeedされるのでしょうか？
それとも、そもそもtensorflowの計算グラフの概念の考え方が違いますでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

変数がfeedされるというのは、「Tensorに値がセットされる」という意味でしょうか？
1と2で差があらわれる例を示していただいた方が、疑問点がわかりやすいです。

Tensorflowの動作としては、
0. 計算グラフが構築される
1. sess.runが実行される
2. placeholder xに値がセットされる
3. tf.addが計算される
という順序になります。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。返信が遅くなってしまい申し訳ございません。自分で何回か実践したところ、自己解決に至りました。また、Tensorflowの動作を簡潔に記載していただきありがとうざいます。勉強になりました。